# MonoTouch.Dialog row animations

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Just wondering if it is possible to have no animations in section when adding/removing elements in the section. Or even when adding/removing the section itself.

On ViewWillAppear I check a global boolean to see if the app has been exited/reopened. This will then cause it to reload new data. (Did have RefreshRequested set up, but the client wanted it this way). So on ViewWillAppear we call a function called UpdateCells which does the following.

```
// Using Bottom animation as its the closest to none (none has no fade effects
// but makes solid cells move upwards in the TableView and then suddenly disappear)
Root.Remove(mySection1, UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom);
Root.Remove(mySection2, UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom);
mySection1.Clear();
mySection2.Clear();
// Load stuff from SQLite DB and populate sections. Adding looks like:
// if (isThisWeek)
// {
//    section1.Insert(0, UITableViewRowAnimation.None, newElement);
// }
// else
// {
//    section2.Insert(0. UITableViewRowAnimation.None, newElement);
// }
// Now finally add sections back into Root if there exists elements in them.
if (sectionThisWeek.Count > 0)
{
    Root.Insert(1, UITableViewRowAnimation.None, sectionThisWeek);
}
if (sectionCommingUp.Count > 0)
{
    Root.Insert(1, UITableViewRowAnimation.None, sectionCommingUp);
}
```

I was hoping for some sort of, pause everything in the DialogViewController, work on it, then do a ReloadComplete() with no animations.. somehow...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or a better way to do what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reloading all the data at once, you can just assign the entire new value to the Root property on the DialogViewController and no animations would be shown.